# Why am i seeing a blank page after being redirected? (NextJS 13 API Route)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, next.js, middleware

Ok so after 2 days of banging my head against a wall with this issue I'm finally raising the white flag and asking the community for some help.

I've recently been asked to implement a basic login system on a new project at my company. We're using NextJS v13 and I'm starting to realise a lot has changed since I last used this framework.

Here is my problem (be kind, I'm still a noob with this kinda thing!).

- Whenever a user lands on a page, I need to make a request to the back end to check if the user is logged in or not.
- If they are NOT, then I want to redirect them to `/login`

Pretty simple right? Well either I'm a moron, or no, it's not lol.

If I have understood things so far then this is how I think it should be done.

in `src/middleware.ts` I'm keeping things as simple as possible to try and eliminate variables. All I'm doing is sending the user to the `authUser` API route, so far so good.

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(req: NextRequest, event: NextFetchEvent) {
  return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL('api/authUser', req.url));
}
```

then in `api/authUser.ts` I'm making a fetch request to the backend to check if the user is logged in or not.
As expected, they are NOT. Which means I get a response on the server `{ error: { message: 'Unauthorized.' } }`
Now when I get that response I'm redirecting to `/login`

```
export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
  const options = {method: 'GET', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', Accept: 'application/json'}};

  fetch('http://localhost:8082/api/auth/user', options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      console.log(req.url);
      if (response.error && req.url !== '/login') {
        res.writeHead(302, {
          Location: '/login'
        });
        res.end();
      }

      res.end();
    })
}

export const config = {
    api:{
        externalResolver: true,
    },
}
```

So now I run `localhost:3000` and I do successfully get redirected to `/login`

BUT

The page is blank, it's not being rendered, but there are no errors in the console, no network errors, status code 200, basically nothing to indicate why my page isn't rendering. I've spent 2 days trying to figure this out and frankly I'm stumped.

I've not written any middleware before and I've not built a login system so all I can think is that I've made a fundamental error earlier in this process and I've turned right when I should have gone left.

Please help, I'm at my wits end :/

Answer (score 0):

When facing blank pages, it's possible that the cause is a timing error in JavaScript's code execution. This can occur when responses from requests arrive after the code has already executed, resulting in a blank page. In such situations, the requested data might appear normal during debugging because they exist, but they were not processed quickly enough by JavaScript. To resolve this issue, i suggest to
try using the async/await statement when making requests.